# In Azure IoT Hub under IoT Edge, is a device a type of hardware or a specific device?

Tags: azure, edge

If I have built a temperature sensor and will install 100 of those, will I then in Azure IoT Hub under IoT Edge have one device (with 100 connected clients?) or will I have 100 devices?

To clarify my question: Can I put the same device connection string in all temperature sensors that I ship?

Comment: This will depend on how you configure the devices

Comment: Can I put the same device connection string in all the devices?

Comment: Why not try (you only need to test with 2) and you can probably just run the code without any hardware.

Comment: Before asking the question I tried all this, what I'm asking is if this is best practice.

Comment: Then update the question with those details add it really isn't clear

Comment: only you know how you want the sensors to behave. .... why are you asking us about what you want? .... we have no way of knowing.

Comment: Please [edit] the question for clarity regarding what you tried and what you want to do. Thank you.

Comment: The edit does not really help to clarify the question. You know the answer to this is 'yes', and you've proven that answer. Presumably there is more to be said about what sort of answer you need (not my field, I can't be more specific).